# Scroll to an Anchor with multiple anchor in uRL,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

Got a question about the `Anchor` point.

I have a URL like *domain*.tld/*sub*/#point1/#point2 and I also using tabs which is triggered by the first `#point1`. So if someone opens the link the browser is detecting the first tab on that page and then it needs to find the second `#point2` which is a anchor point like `<div id="point2"></div>`.

But now comes te question, since it is not possible to use multiple anchor scrolldowns when the pages is loaded, I have to find a other option. But offcourse didn't have that much experience. Who could help me out?

Regards Martijn

Comment: Just point to the last inner anchor, just use `domain.tld/sub/#point2`.

Comment: It is not possible since the page is categorized with multiple tabs!

Comment: How is that? Can you please share your code?

Comment: The code you provided is not enough for a proper answer. You could always get the url text, split it by #, then get the last chunk, make it a new <a> tag, add it to the dom, trigger a click on it and then remove it. A big walk-around but it will work. Or provide sample code for a better solution.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis do you have a code sample or URL with that solution? Guess this will stand. Otherwise, I saw a more like same issue and they using URL parameters and catch them from the url and set a scrollTo on top.

Comment: Instead of triggering a click on an <a> element I added a scrolltop approach but keep in mind that if you have a fixed header or something in your page you should calculate it's height and subtract it from your  lastItem.offset().top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I changed the answer from Stavros a bit like underneath:

```
$(function() {
    goToUrl();


    function goToUrl() {
    var newUrl      = document.URL;
    var newUrlArr   = newUrl.split("?target=");
    var defUrl = newUrlArr[1].slice(0, newUrlArr[1].indexOf("#"));

    var newUrlArrLength = defUrl.length;
    if (newUrlArrLength>0) {
        var tag = $("#"+defUrl+"");
         $(window).scrollTop(tag.offset().top);
    }
}

});
```

This does the job for me! Thanks Stavros.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    goToUrl();
});


function goToUrl() {
    var newUrl      = document.URL;
    var newUrlArr   = newUrl.split("#");
    var newUrlArrLength = newUrlArr.length;
    if (newUrlArrLength>0) {
        var last = parseInt(newUrlArrLength) -1;
        var lastUrl         = newUrlArr[last];
        var lastItem        = $("#"+lastUrl);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: lastItem.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```